# infragistics igGrid: how to remove a row with javascript

Tags: javascript, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

i think my question is pretty simple but i still didn't find any answer that fits me, neither here nor out there..
so i'd be really happy if someone could help me out, it doesn't matter if it's by providing useful links or whatever...

what i'm trying to achieve:
i've got an Ignite UI Grid (igGrid), where i'd like to remove a row using javascript. it doesn't even matter which one. simple, right?

what i've tried so far:

- **$(row).remove();** -> in this case every single row is being removed
- **$(row).remove(1);** -> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'
- **get_rows():** not supported by javascript, it would work in c# though..
- **removeat-method:** not supported by javascript, it would work in c# though..
- **igGridSelection:** selected stuff that i want to keep will be removed, too

and now the code snippet:

```
    $sender = $(this).attr('id');
    $varTablName = gridMap.getVarTable($sender);
    var rowCount = $("#" + $varTablName).igGrid("widget").igGrid('rows').length;

    $("#" + $varTablName).igGrid("widget").igGrid('rows').each(function (index) {
        var row = $("#" + $varTablName).igGrid("widget").igGrid("rowAt", index);
        if (rowCount > 1) {
            $(row).remove(); //the not quite working part
        }
```

it's doable, right? there's no need to go all the way and write it in c# and call it with js, right..? RIGHT??^^

Comment: thanks to everyone..! i havn't a solution yet and i don't think i will find it today. but i'll start all over again on monday with fresh spirit and my collegues who aren't at the office today.. 
so as soon as i know more i'll tell you so that it may help someone else one day... cheers!

Comment: thanks to bfmags i came up with this solution:
    $("#" + $varTablName).igGrid("widget").igGrid('rows').each(function (index) {
        if (index >= 1) {
                  $(this).css("display", 'none');
        }

        });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Infragistics guide to deleting a row programmatically](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/jQuery/2014.1/CLR4.0/html/igGrid_Updating.html#deleting_row_programmatically)

```
$('#grid').igGridUpdating('deleteRow', "AFG");  
$('#grid').igGridUpdating('deleteRow', 1, $('#grid').igGrid("rowAt", 0));
```

Following to the [api docs](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2014.1/ui.igGridUpdating#methods:deleteRow) -- thnx @KonstantinDinev -- the code above will delete a row from the grid, creating a transaction and updates the UI. This functionality depends on [autoCommit](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/jQuery/2011.2/CLR4.0/HTML/igGrid_Updating.html) option of igGrid

**the API should always be first option ^^**

We can also target the dom element and remove or hide it ourselves. When removed the number of rows displayed changes but the data source will need to be updated

http://jsfiddle.net/gtw916um/6/

```
$(function() {
  $("#grid").igGrid({});

  //hides 2nd row (index starts at 0)
  $("#grid").igGrid("allRows").each(function(index) {
    if (index == 1) {
      $(this).css("display", 'none');
    }
  });

  //deletes 4th row (index starts at 0)
  var row = $("#grid").igGrid("widget").igGrid("rowAt", 3);
  $(row).remove();

  //un-hiding 2nd row (index starts at 0)
  row = $("#grid").igGrid("widget").igGrid("rowAt", 1);
  $(row).css("display", 'table-row');

});
```

*untested update data method*

```
$("#grid").data("igGrid").dataSource.deleteRow(3, true);
$("#grid").data("igGrid").commit();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but unfortunately this doesn't work with removing rows. (deleteRow just deletes the data in the row, but the row itself still stays there..)

Comment: can you get the row id ? var id = row.attr("data-id"); $(id).remove();

Comment: no, not the way you described (Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'). 
but i tried 
            var RemoveRowId = $($("#" + $sender).igGrid("widget").igGrid("rowAt", args.row.index)).attr("data-id");

this doesn't throw any exceptions, but doesn't remove anything either...
i'm beginning to think the problem i have is called ME...^^'

Comment: jsfiddle.net/gtw916um/6 details above

Comment: thanks! it works now, but i had to give up on removing. so your first solution almost worked perfectly (just changed into (index >= 1) ), sorry for being so stubborn last friday^^

Comment: deleteRow does not just delete the data, it also deletes the row element: http://jsfiddle.net/gtw916um/8/

Comment: thnx @KonstantinDinev updated the answer, but couldn't get your jsfiddle to work

Answer (score 1):

`deleteRow` is the method you're looking for as the [other answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36500633/1348324). For this method you can provide the row element as parameter, or the row ID. [Here's the API docs](http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2014.1/ui.igGridUpdating#methods:deleteRow).

Here's the code:

```
var row = $("#" + $varTablName).igGrid("rowAt", index);
$("#" + $varTablName).igGridUpdating("deleteRow", row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this or some jquery equivalent. I don't know how it will affect the ultragrid though, so doublecheck if you retain all other functionality.

```
var row = document.querySelector('myRowReference');
row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
```

Comment: hmm.. this looks fine to me, but i cant make it work.. just to be sure if i got you right.. this is what i tried:             
var tmpRow = document.querySelector('id', 1);
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
edit: well, it worked in a sense.. it didn't throw any exceptions, but it still ended up deleting everything...